# How to detect end of initialization in Scala

Tags: scala, initialization

I have the following patern (simplified)
I write a trait "Library" as a template for a collection of books:

```scala
trait Library {
  export Library.*
  private val catalogue = mutable.Map["String", Book] = mutable.Map()

  def writeBook(name:String, content: () => String) : Book = {
    // check if books can be recovered from serialization...
    val newBook = Book(name, content())
    catalogue(name) = newBook
    newBook
  }

  // When initialization is finished
  serialize(catalogue)



}
object Library {
  class Book(name:String, content: String) {
    ...
  }
```

I've skipped the details about how the serialization should be used in `writeBook`.
Then, the user can do:

```scala
object MyLibrary extends Library {

  val aliceInWonderland = newBook("Alice In Wonderland", ???)

  val warAndPeace= newBook("War and Peace", ???)
}
```

The important part is that computing the books content can be really expensive and hence can be cached between run. Moreover, for efficiency, it is important that the `catalogue` is cached at once and not individually for each book.

I have now two questions:

- How can I run my `serialize` function at the good moment and transparently for the user, without using the deprecated `delayedInit`?
- Assume I have a main method in `library`, so that the user can run each of their MyLibrary objects, doing whatever. How can I pass an argument from the command line to the initializer to activate or disactive the serialization?

I've thought all day about this and can't find a workaround that keeps each of the MyLibrary object free of anything not related too the books themselve (that's important). Any idea what a suitable workaround for the deprecated `delayedInit` might be?

Comment: Personally, rather than this whole mutable and magic approach. Just make `Library` a `final class` that receives a `List[BookInfo]` in the constructor.

Comment: That would break a lot of features relying on extending the Library class, which, among other things, can provide a big DSL (like in my actual application) and a main function that allows to run the MyLibrary objects. More generally, it's a complete change of the codebase with a lot of consequences, not really a solution to the problem shown.

Comment: Them make Book constructor private or package private and require obtaining  book through some API, which would create new and put it into cache or obtain it from there. Then books would be created _only_ if they were requested _when_ they would be requested.

Comment: That's also an obvious solution, but as I said for efficiency purpose books should be serialized together (reason being that, for example, they share a lot of common words which can be reused)

Comment: If anyone can create a new instance at arbitrary moment, you cannot came up with any bulletproof way of making sure that effective batch for any purpose (e.g. serialization) can be formed. At best your logic sounds like the code should acknowledge statefulness, obtain things through some service, make this service responsible for creating instances and caching them as if they were fetched from DB or external service, perhaps put them on some queue (to form batch of all things made e.g. the last 10s) and periodically flush the cache to prevent OOM. Doing this in constructor sounds like an abuse

Comment: Bulletproof way is not necessary. In the developed DSL, it is not expected that books are instantiated in any other way than the one specified in the example, if it happen then so be it and it will not benefits from serialization. It also make sense, for export, that books are gathered according to their host file. It is also important that books can be referred and used directly from other objects. The program is, indeed, stateful though this does not really appear to the user. I haven't found a way to have this happen outside the constructor, but if you know one please let me know.

Comment: Do you need to keep the client code completely unchanged or do you have some wiggle room?